# Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hive, metastore

i just installed hive and mysql..
and copied the mysqlconnector to the hive_home/lib folder

but when i try show databases and create table commands in the hive> prompt giving me the error as below:

```
create database saty;
FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

and my hive_site.xml is

```
<property>    
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>         
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoop?CreateDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>         
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

and i dont have a directory called /user/hive/warehouse in my file system.

i created these path with mkdir command.. and tried after reboot..
bout still getting the error..

regards,
satya

Answer (score 2):

Try Specifying these two properties

```
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>username</value>
<description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>password</value>
<description>Password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
```

And Similarly the username of your mysql login should have the permission to access the db sepcified in the JDBC connection string. This Can be acheived using the following command

```
GRANT ALL ON Databasename.* TO username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is located at http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/5.0/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_hive_schema_tool.html

To suppress the schema check and allow the metastore to implicitly modify the schema, you need to set the hive.metastore.schema.verification configuration property to false in hive-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and the cause in my case was selinux where it prevented Postgres from proper running.

I inserted following line to the first line of /etc/rc3.d/S64postgresql -

echo 0 > /selinux/enforce   # Disable selinux temporarily

and restarted the node with the hive metastore.

So generally you can check two things:

1. Check whether the DB for the metastore is running properly
2. Whether the user/passwd from the property is correct

Answer (score 0):

reconfigure your hive using -hiveconf hive.root.logger=warn,console than find the detail reason that why you could not instantiate your hive mate store client.

The problem i met was wrong mysql configuration, the error message is "Binary logging not possible. Message: Transaction level 'READ-COMMITTED' in InnoDB is not safe for binlog mode 'STATEMENT'". When i change binlog_format from "statement" to "binlog_format=mixed", then hive meta store client instantiate successfully.

Hope it work for you.